# how can i restrict vat for particular countries

Tags: php, magento

For some reason, one of our websites is only applying VAT to the UK and no other countries.

We need it to apply to all counties within Europe. Outside of Europe it should not be applied.

we are using magento.. and we are not able to find the exact problem..

can anyone help for this setting from Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Zones & Rates.?

we set Tax Identifier: VAT Standard
Country and State: United Kingdom
Rate Percent: 20.00

but now we want to add it to all countries within europ

can anyone define exact steps to setup this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use below link to import tax rate for all EU country

http://www.meteorify.com/2012/03/quick-tip-setup-eu-tax-rates-in-magento-quickly/

let me know if i can help you more

Comment: in above link go to the page and already describe steps to import tax rates

Comment: link is nt gvng the rslt we wnt :( can u provide link again?